# How do i detect collision and stack falling objects in as3 flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a little problem when I'm trying to get the sqares to stack, almost like in tetris. 
I don't know how I can controll the different squares so i can check for collision. I have made one square with as3 linkage name Square.

```
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(12);

    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, doStuff);

    timer.start();

    var newSquare= new Square();
    nyFirkant.y = 0;
    nyFirkant.x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4) * 100;
    addChild(newSquare);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, tastLytter);

    function keyListener(evt:KeyboardEvent)
    {
    var key:int = evt.keyCode;

    if (key== Keyboard.RIGHT && newSquare.x < 400)
      {
        newSquare.x +=  100;
    }
   if (key== Keyboard.LEFT && newSquare.x > 0)
    {
        newSquare.x -=  100;
    }

    }


    function doStuff(evt:TimerEvent)
    {
    if (newSquare.y <= 400 - newSquare.height)
    {
        newSquare.y = newSquare.y + 2;
    }
    if (newSquare.y == 350)
    {
        newSquare= new Square();
        newSquare.y = 0;
        newSquare.x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4) * 100;;

        addChild(newSquare);

    }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hitTestObject, it's a method in the MovieClip class.

```
if (firstBlock.hitTestObject(secondBlock)) {
    trace("This block hit the other block");
    //Do stuff
}
```

Obviously this isn't a "drop-in" solution - you'd be much better off using a physics engine such as [Box2D](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/), but hitTestObject should do fine for your purposes.